# C1FlexGrid Combobox

Tags: vb.net, c1flexgrid

I am trying to populate comboboxes in accordance to a value in the flexgrid that is on the same row. However it changes per each row on the flexgrid. I need to populate a combobox based of that row and column. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood ur question u need to put a combobox inside ur C1FlexGrid and dropdown of ur combobox list contains each row elements. Put this Code where u want to load data into combobox

```
Dim dtMap As Specialized.ListDictionary = New Specialized.ListDictionary()
Dim tmpStyle As CellStyle
dtMap.Clear()
For j As Integer = 1 To fgMain.Rows.Count - 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To fgMain.Cols.Count - 1
        dtMap.Add(i , C1FlexGrid1(j ,i))
    Next
Next
tmpStyle =C1FlexGrid1.Styles.Add("Name")
' integer is data type of data selected into ur combobox. here it's the type of i 
' cause i is the key of value in dtMap "every item n ListDictionary dtMap contains key and value"
'so u just change this i and integer to what u need
tmpStyle.DataType = GetType(Integer)
tmpStyle.DataMap = dtMap
C1FlexGrid1.Cols(2).Style = tmpStyle
DbReader.Close()
MyCmd.Dispose()
```

I hope this will help u